# What is a biodroid in Ghost in the Shell?

Tags: ghost-in-the-shell-sac

In the episode 24 of GITS SAC 2nd GIG it becomes apparent that the member of Section 9, usually referred to as Proto, is actually not a human, but a "biodroid" prototype. What exactly is it and how different it is from cyberized people and androids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the name suggests, a [bioroid](http://ghostintheshell.wikia.com/wiki/Bioroid) is an android, but built with human body parts-- except that they don't have a human brain.

The Major is a cyberized human, and an android is the least human of the three.

Comment: Saying he doesn't have a "human" brain is a bit misleading.  In Appleseed (a related work from the same author) Bioroids are essentially clones/engineered humans, so by default have "human" (ish) brains.  Perhaps you meant they don't have a brain from an "actual" human?

Comment: We are not talking about Appleseed. I looked up Appleseed's bioroid definition as well, and it's different.

Are GiTS bioroids the same? Think about Proto, who is GiTS' biorod, by the end of the show.